# Distinct TimeoutException from SoapException

Tags: c#, web-services, soapexception

Let me sketch the the situation. I have a *Windows-Service (lets name it `A`)* which *`calls` a Web-Service (lets name him `B`)*. *`B` calls* upon different *Web-Services himself. (lets call those Web-Services `WS1`,`WS2`,`WS3`)*

Drawing:

```
                       //This is a Black Box (e.g. I can't change implementation)
                       +-----------------------------------------------+
                       |                                               |
                       |                  ----> WS1                    |
WindowsService A ----> |   Webservice B   ----> WS2                    |
                       |                  ----> WS3                    |
                       |                                               |
                       +-----------------------------------------------+
```

From time to time exceptions may occur during the calls. *Most exceptions* should *stop the executing* of the program and notify the developer (Me). But when a `Timeout` occurs then Window-Service `A` should attempt a `retry`.

So I've written the following code:

```
try
{}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
    {
        //Wait some time before retry
        //Log the exception
        //Retry
    }
    else
    {
         //Log the exception
         throw;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     //Log the exception
     throw;
}
```

*This code works* brilliantly if the *exception occurs in Web-Service `B`*. Yet when the `timeout` occurs in `WS1`,`WS2`,`WS3`; I'm getting a `SoapException`.

**Question:**
Is there anyway to filter out if the cause of the `SoapException` was a `Timeout` without using the message as mentioned here ([MSDN- Handle TimeoutException](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/34a8ca63-5dce-450c-a317-59f83791ddcd/handle-timeout-exception)). Is there any field that could point to the type of the underlying exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it might help you realize the cause of the error:
PS: Use it within `catch()`

```
string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
return pageContent;
```

Comment: Problem is, the `SoapException` doesn't inherit from `WebException`. So i can't use the `Response-Property`. The `Webexception-part`works brilliantly. Its the SoapExceptions that are bugging me.

Comment: Believe me i had the same problem some time back, but allowing SOAP to throw it's exception onto WebException part helped a lot to atleast weed out the error occuring parts. In my case i had not given the header format right, which was- The Header format is : text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"; action=\"headtrip\";"

Comment: The Header format was : text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"; action=\"headtrip\";

Comment: As far as i'm aware, there is no way to cast a `SoapException` to `Webexception`. And i can't change the exception thrown from the services aswell.